# chain rule: $g(x)=(2ra^{rx}+n)^p$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

looking for my mistake and I can't find it. here is the layout:

$g(x)=(2ra^{rx}+n)^p$

$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (2ra^{rx}+n)'$

$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (2ra^{rx})'+(n)'$

$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (n)'+[(2)' (ra^{rx}) + (ra^{rx})'  (2)]$

$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (n)'+[(2)' (ra^{rx}) + (2) [(r)'(a^{rx})+(a^{rx})'(r)]]$

$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (n)'+[(2)' (ra^{rx}) + (2) [(r)'(a^{rx})+(r)a^{rx}\ln(a)(rx)']]$

which when finally unpacked should be:
$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1} (n)'+[(2)'(ra^{rx}) + (2) [(r)' (a^{rx})+(r)a^{rx}\ln(a)rx]]$

the answer i got was:
$$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1}+2a^{rx}+2r^{2}xa^{rx}\ln(a)$$

the answer says:

$$2r^{2}p(\ln a)(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1}a^{rx}$$

Comment: Third line and onwards: mistake in parentheses after splitting the sum. You split the sum and then you forget to multiple both terms (with the term on the LHS of the $*$), but you multiple the first and only add the second.

Comment: In TeX and LaTeX and in this stripped-down thing called MathJax that is used here, one can write $2\cdot5$ or $2\times5$.  The notation $2*5$ is for use when one is limited to the symbols on a keyboard.  At a state dinner at Buckingham Palace hosted by the Queen, one doesn't eat by pushing one's face into the plate when silverware is available.  I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $(n)'=(2)'=(r)'=0.$ That simplifies things greatly.

Bear in mind also that you should have $$p(2ra^{rx}+n)^{p-1}\cdot\bigl((n)'+[(2)'\cdot(ra^{rx})+2\cdot[(r)'\cdot(a^{rx})+(r)\cdot a^{rx}\ln(a)\cdot r]]\bigr).$$ Note the added grouping symbols, and the fact that $(rx)'=r\ne rx.$

You will also make your life a great deal simpler by recalling/noting that when $f(x)$ is differentiable and $c$ is a constant, then $$\bigl(c\cdot f(x)\bigr)'=c\cdot f'(x).$$ This will save you multiple unnecessary uses of the product rule, since then we immediately see that $$(2ra^{rx}+n)'=(2ra^{rx})'+(n)'=2r(a^{rx})'+0,$$ and from there we continue in much the same way that you did.

Comment: thanks, I forgot that the (r)' was not 1. Is it safe to say that whatever letter is shown in the function (IE:x in G(x)) would allow the derivative to be 1? (in this case any (x)' would be 1, but no other letter?)

Comment: Unless it is assumed that another variable is a function depending on $x,$ yes.